# Find the largest of the even-numbered component values in file

Tags: prolog

*sorry for possible mistakes, I'm not a native speaker*

Hi! Here is how my task sounds:

We have a file, the components of which are real numbers. Display the highest value of the component with an even number on the screen

- When creating a program, it is necessary to use standard Prolog predicates: predicates for working with files, data input and output, character processing and timing, program management predicates.
- Requests must be implemented using the appropriate goal section.

Here is my code:

```
% Predicate for finding the largest value among even-numbered components
find_max_even_component(File, Max) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    read_numbers(Stream, Numbers), % Call the predicate to read data from the file
    close(Stream), % Closing the file
    find_max_even_component(Numbers, Max). % Call the internal predicate

% Internal predicate for finding the maximum value
find_max_even_component([X], X).
find_max_even_component([X, Y | Rest], Max) :-
    X >= Y,
    find_max_even_component([X | Rest], Max).
find_max_even_component([X, Y | Rest], Max) :-
    X < Y,
    find_max_even_component([Y | Rest], Max).

% Predicate for reading data from a file
read_numbers(Stream, []) :- at_end_of_stream(Stream), !.
read_numbers(Stream, [X | Rest]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream), % Until the end of the file is reached
    read(Stream, X), % Read a number from a file
    read_numbers(Stream, Rest). % Read other numbers recursively

goal :- find_max_even_component('test.txt', Max),
        write('The highest value among even-numbered components: '), write(Max), nl.
```

**test.txt** looks like:
 `1 2 3 4 5`
It is located in the same folder as **test.pl**

Then, I'm trying to run my program in SWI-Prolog like this:

```
?- consult("test.pl").
true.

?- goal.
```

And after that, I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\test.txt:1:11: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file
```

I tried to clear the previous definitions with `make.` and restart the program, but it didn't help. What could be a mistake?

**UPD**
I changed test.txt and now it looks like this:
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.

So now I have a new error after using `?- goal.`:

```
ERROR: source_sink `[1,2,3,4,5]' does not exist (No such file or directory)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] open([1,2|...],read,_166)
ERROR:   [12] find_max_even_component([1,2|...],_204) at /Users/lidarachynska/Documents/lab2-rach-folder/test.pl:5
ERROR:   [10] goal at /Users/lidarachynska/Documents/lab2-rach-folder/test.pl:26
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user:goal) at /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1173
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
   Exception: (12) find_max_even_component([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], _42) ?
```

Comment: the problem might be in reading file or file permissions. but I couldn't find anything helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your internal procedure has the exact same name and arity as your public procedure (`find_max_even_component/2`).

You need to change the name of the internal procedure to something else, e.g. `find_max_item/2`.